# WebGL frame rate slows down after triggering javascript event

Tags: unity, javascript, webgl

I am using Unity WebGL to host my game on a flask server and trying to throw a warning to the user whenever he tries to navigate away from the tab or mistakenly click browser's back button. Each time after the event is triggered (whenever I try to navigate away) the game slows down with a huge drop in frame rate (navigation has to be performed after the game has been loaded properly by showing the unity logo and other stuffs). Here is the script that I am using to trigger the event:

```
<script>           
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) 
        {   
            var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

            e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
            return confirmationMessage;             
        });
 </script>
```

What is the work-around of this problem and why the game slows down completely?